# Jasmine: Test nested function is been called or not

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm new to writing unit test case,

MY service spec,

```
  it('should call createComponent ', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'createComponent');
    service.setRootViewContainerRef(oneColumnTemplateComponent.view);

  it('should call redirect ', () => {
    spyOn(renderEngineService, 'createComponent');
    service.createComponent(oneColumnTemplateComponent.content, 'UndefinedComponent');
    expect(renderEngineService.redirect).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I wanted to test, if `createComponent` is not valid it should call the `redirect` method.

How can this be done ? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your second test case / spy definition, I think you want to spy on `redirect` and not `createComponent`. Also do you want to mock the `createComponent` call or just let it go through and check if it was called? Depending on that the, test case would have to be written a bit different.

Anyway, I would change it to the following (if you intend to not mock the `createComponent` call):

```
it('should call createComponent ', () => {
  // add callThrough if you want the actual function to be called, otherwise remove it
  let spy = spyOn(renderEngineService, 'createComponent').and.callThrough();
  renderEngineService.setRootViewContainerRef(oneColumnTemplateComponent.view);
  renderEngineService.createComponent(oneColumnTemplateComponent.content, 'HeadingComponent');
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it('should call redirect ', () => {
  // spy on redirect here, not createComponent
  let spy = spyOn(renderEngineService, 'redirect');
  renderEngineService.setRootViewContainerRef(oneColumnTemplateComponent.view);
  // pass null as second argument, otherwise redirect will not be called
  renderEngineService.createComponent(oneColumnTemplateComponent.content, null);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```